# SQL Server Using Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a very simple query that looks at a large table of locations and returns details about specific street. I am trying to get high - low numbers to populate another single row and have elected to use a FUNCTION to do this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMaxStrNo]
    (@StrFullName varchar) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
        (SELECT  
             MAX(CAST(apt_no AS INT)) 
         FROM
             location 
         WHERE
             location_name = @StrFullName 
             AND ISNUMERIC(apt_no) = 1)
END
GO
```

Try as I might the results come back as NULL when called from my main procedure

```
SET @MaxStrNo = dbo.GetMaxStrNo (@StrFullName)
```

Any help would be most gratefully appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Might be you are passing the value which doesn't exist in the table

Comment: StrFullName varchar is StrFullName varchar(1), so probably you don't have location_name in the database equal to the first letter of StrFullName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first obvious problem is the declaration `varchar()`.  In SQL Server, this should always have a length:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMaxStrNo](
    @StrFullName varchar(max)
) RETURNS INT
```

The rest of your function has another problem.  The `isnumeric()` in the `where` clause will not prevent an error.  Use `try_convert()` to prevent an error:

```
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT MAX(TRY_CONVERT(int, apt_no)) 
            FROM location 
            WHERE location_name = @StrFullName and ISNUMERIC(apt_no) = 1
           );
END;
```

The `isnumeric()` in the `where` clause is strictly optional in this case.

Comment: Many Thanks Gordon ... Worked first time ... All those ohours, need to get an expert or at least rewad a book :) Cheers